# Why is spark condition for uniqueness of $l_0$ optimization too strong?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, inverse-problems

In $l_0$ minimization problem, finding sparsest solution to $Ax=b$ for an $m$ by $n$ matrix, uniqueness of the solution can be guaranteed via spark in the following way. Spark is defined as the smallest number of columns from $A$ that are linearly dependent.

[Taken from Elad, Sparse and Redundant Representations]

If a system of linear equations $Ax=b$ has a solution $x$ obeying $||x||_{0}
< \frac{\textrm{spark }A}{2}$, this solution is necessarily the sparsest possible.

I understand the proof of the theorem but I am struggling with the following.
Let $x^{*}$ be a k-sparse vector, at most $k$ non-zero components, consider
$b = Ax^{*}$. Let $A$ has spark $m+1$, for example a Gaussian matrix. Now if we solve the $l_0$ minimization problem, shouldn't it suffice to have $k\le m$. I don't see why the spark needs a stronger condition.

Thank you for any hints or suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the solution is not unique or there is another sparser vector $y^*$ which is the solution to:
$$
\min \|x\|_0\\
s.t. Ax=b.
$$
Therefore we have $Ax^*=Ay^*$, which means that $A(x^*-y^*)=0$. Note that this implies that there are $\|x^*-y^*\|_0$ number of columns that are linearly dependent. This means that $\text{spark}(A)\leq \|x^*-y^*\|_0$. However:
$$
\|x^*-y^*\|_0\leq 2\|x^*\|_0.
$$
Therefore $\text{spark}(A)\leq 2\|x^*\|_0$, which goes against the assumption that $\text{spark}(A)>2\|x^*\|_0$. So this condition is sufficient condition for a solution to be the sparsest.

---

From the proof, one can construct a counterexample for the case $\text{spark}(A)\leq 2\|x^*\|_0$, which includes your case $\text{spark}(A)=m+1$ and $\|x^*\|_0=k$ and $k< m+1\leq 2k$. Consider $m+1$ linearly dependent column vector of $A$, which means that there is a vector $z$ for which $Az=0$ and $\|z\|_0=m+1$. You can write $z$ as $z_1+z_2$ such that $\|z_1\|_0=k$ and $0<\|z_2\|_0=m+1-k\leq k$. Suppose that $b_1=Az_1$ and consider the following OP:
$$
\min \|x\|_0\\
s.t. Ax=b_1.
$$
Then $z_1$ is a $k-$solution to this problem but it is neither unique nor necessarily the sparsest. Because $Az_1=A(-z_2)$ and $\|z_2\|_0\leq k=\|z_1\|_0$. This means that $z_2$ is either sparser or has $k$ non-zero elements like $z_1$.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have two questions. (1) why can we consider m dependent column vectors of A? Since spark(A)=m+1, any m columns are linearly independent, unless I am mistaken. (2) I like the argument above which is what I have been trying to do in vain for hours. In the example you give, why is $z_1$ not a unique solution? Thank you

Comment: For (1) it was a type as you could see I mentioned later $\|z\|_0=m+1$. For (2) see that $-z_2$ is also a solution and $\|z_2\|_0\leq k=\|z_1\|_0$. I added that also in the text.

Comment: thank you so much. Now, I see it and understand it very well.